# awk - How to get the position of a word, defined as a variable, in a line

Tags: awk

Suppose we have this file x.txt:

```
head -1 x.txt

1 234 black xipo 23
```

I have this variable $color:

```
echo $color

black
```

I'd like to get the position of $color, in case, black, inside the line, using awk.

I tried this code, but I haven't achieved good results.

```
head -1 $filename | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i==$color ) { print i } }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v color=black '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i==color ) { print i } }}'
```

-v pass var to awk script, and in awk script ,there is  no $ before variables name ,